# Is it possible to read/ write directly to LSM6DSL registers?

Tags: movesense

I would like to use some features of LSM6DSL, which are not supported by movesense API yet. Is it possible to read and write directly to LSM6DSL registers? Does the movesense API already have some functions to do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that at the moment. It would also make your sensor software really sensitive for any hardware or Movesense core software changes so it is not a really good idea.

If you want to access a feature on the LSM6DSL (which is the current chip in HW >= G1) and there is no API for it yet, add a feature request in the [Bitbucket issues of the movesense-device-lib repository](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/issues).

*Full disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*